# Detect symbol on paper

Tags: image-processing, opencv, aforge, vision

I want to detect a symbol drawn by the user on a piece of paper. This symbol will be specified  by the documentation so every user draws the same symbol but differences will exist of course because of each user's unique handwriting.

1. What kind of symbol should I choose? What is easily recognizable but also makes the detection tolerant to minor modifications (by each user's hand)?
2. What pattern matching method/algorithm should I use for detection of the symbol in a document image?

Comment: There are may papers/tutorials/articles about what you're asking. Do you know what is Google?

Comment: Your comment is not helpful without providing links to papers or algorithm names.

Comment: Google often lists stackoverflow as first results to me, so it is very pratical to have answers and quality links here, because they can be easily find.

Answer (score 2):

The question deals with an aspect of document image analysis thats interesting, but quite rudimentary.

1. For your question 1. its something best decided on your own. Can you
   honestly not think of any such symbol? Assuming you have some time
   to try out a few symbols and recognition results ... quite simple to
   be answered by self. Hint: think in terms of touchscreens on phones.
   They often have Gesture Recognition - usually for something like
   locking the screen, or even shortcuts. What sort of gestures are
   usually used - look at the [screenshots](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gestureshortcuts&hl=en) here please.
2. The recognition is way more interesting. Assuming that the symbol is
   drawn on a clear and visible sheet of paper and can be easily
   separated as an object from the image (by connected components,
   available in OpenCV), try matching Moments. Either simple moments, or
   Hu invariant moments, both of which are present in OpenCV. For
   simple hand-drawn symbols these should be sufficient.